# merging two multi level class objects with element update c#

Tags: c#, linq

I have two objects (A,B) of same class type (`PPLWebOperatorGridList`). I need update the `A.OldValue` with `B.Value`.

I have tried by adding the guid property and update it in the constructor as shown below. But these object list may repeat same value:

```
public PPLWebOperatorGridList()
    {
        this.guid = this.FieldName+this.TagName+
                    this.Length+this.Encoder+this.Value;
    }
    public string guid { get; set; }
```

I have tried as below. I know there are bugs in it but consider the idea in it.

```
private List<PPLWebOperatorGridList> UpddateOldValues(List<PPLWebOperatorGridList> customeTlvList, List<PPLWebOperatorGridList> customeTlvList2)
    {
        foreach (var list in customeTlvList)
        {
            foreach (var list1 in customeTlvList2)
            {
                if (list.guid == list1.guid)
                {
                    list.OldValue = list1.Value;
                    if (list.children.Count > 0)
                        UpddateOldValues(list.children.ToList(), list1.children.ToList());
                }
            }                
        }

        return customeTlvList;
    }
```

The guid property may be same for some in the list.

```
class PPLWebOperatorGridList
{
    public bool expanded { get; set; }
    public string FieldName { get; set; }
    public string TagName { get; set; }
    public string Length { get; set; }
    public string Encoder { get; set; }
    public string Value { get; set; }
    public List<PPLWebOperatorGridList> children { get; set; }
    public string OldValue { get; set; }
}
```

I need to loop through based on index and update the `A.OldValue` with `B.Value`. I am not very familiar with linq, so please suggest a solution.

Comment: what did you try so far?

Comment: I have tried by adding the guid property and update it in the constructor as shown below and looped through and tried to update. But these object list may repeat with same values.

Comment: show us what you did please

Comment: To be able to join the A object with the B object you need a unique property like ID or name (a primary key).  Are any of the PPLWebOperatorGridList properties give a one-to-one mapping between A and B?

Comment: thanks jdweng. there is no Primary key kid of property. But i have update my question. Is there a way to update the guid property with a sequence. which will be the same for both objects.